# Developing a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I know I can do this with itertools, but I'm actually trying to learn how to start working with recursions.

I want to take the two values in this list...

```
[0, 1]
```

...and create a list of lists that contain it's permutations:

```
[ [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1] ]
```

I can do it with a comprehension and loops:

```
[ [i, j] for i in range(0, 2) for j in range(0, 2) ]
```

But that doesn't really scale well.

So if someone could help me understand how to do this with a recursive function that would scale to an arbitrary number of values in the original list I would appreciate it.

Comment: In what way do you want it to scale?

Comment: If you're interested, you can see the code for `itertools.product` here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: @AntonisChristofides: if the original list contains significantly more than two elements, the 'for' loops will eventually become unmanageable.

Comment: @Haidro: Thanks. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Those are not permutations. Permutations of this list would be [0,1] and [1,0]. You mean sth like combinations of n elements, taken from a base set.

Comment: @JohannesCharra: OK, I'll buy that. But the fundamental question remains - how to develop that set of combinations with a recursive function instead of for loops.

Comment: I don't think this is a good problem for recursion (I mean that the problem can be solved by a very simple non-recursive algorithm)

Comment: @Don: I would be very interested in seeing that non-recursive algorithm if it can scale to handle arbitrary ranges -- e.g, (0, n) -- without having to change the algorithm (the way I would need to change the comprehension I wrote).

Answer (score 4):

```
def cartesian_product(base, n=0):
        if (n ==  len(base)-1):
                return [[i] for i in base]
        res = []
        for i in base:
                for element in cartesian_product(base, n+1):
                        res.append([i]+element)
        return res
```

**Input: ** cartesian_product([1,2])

**Output: ** [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

Not the best way to do, but it's recursive.
Each element is composed of one of the base element (1 or 2 in the exemple) + one element of the previous size (so [1] or [2]).